# Do I need to restart nodejs after using npm to install a package?

Tags: node.js

After installing a package using npm. Then I wish to use the package, do i need to restart nodejs? If yes, why?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question. You will need to modify your code to make use of the new module... so yes, you have to restart that particular node process.

Comment: So your answer is yes, I need to restart the node process? What exactly is hard to understand about the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Modules are cached on first require, if you use a module that gets updated when running `npm install`, the running process will keep using the cached version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node-dev Module which will automatically restart your server when you do any change

https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev